# Inequality of some natural numbers

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Let $a,m,n\in\mathbb{N}$,$a>1$, $m=pq$, where $p,q$ are primes and define the number

$$x_{m}=(-1)^n[(a^\frac{m}{gcd(m,n)}-1)^{gcd(m,n)}-(a^\frac{q}{gcd(q,n)}-1)^{gcd(q,n)}-(a^\frac{p}{gcd(p,n)}-1)^{gcd(p,n)}+(a-1)]$$

I must to prove that $x_{m}\neq 0$

**My Aproach** Case 1: gcd(pq,n)=1. In this case

$$x_{m}=(-1)^{n}[a^{pq}-a^{p}-a^{q}+a]$$

Let suppose that $x_{m}=0$. Then

$$a^{pq}-a^{p}-a^{q}+a=0$$

$$\rightarrow a[a^{pq-1}-a^{p-1}-a^{q-1}+1]=0$$

$$\rightarrow [a^{pq-1}-a^{p-1}-a^{q-1}+1]=0$$

$$\rightarrow -a^{pq-1}+a^{p-1}+a^{q-1}=+1$$

$$\rightarrow a|1$$

which is imposible because $a>1$

Comment: What have you tried?  Where did you hit your problems?

Comment: I'm trying with the case gcd(m,n)=1. It is a problem from a book of my supervisor on elementary number theory

Comment: what happens if p or q aren't divisors of n ?

Comment: If $p$ or $q$ aren't divisors of $n$ it is easy to see that $x_{m}=(-1)^n[a^{pq}-a^{p}-a^{q}+a}]$ and by an dividibility argument one can see that $x_{m}\neq 0$

Comment: @JoseCamarillo: You should [edit your question](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/3349781/edit) to include your thoughts. Comments are easily overlooked (and are sometimes hidden).

Answer (score 2):

Begin by noting that $(-1)^n$ changes the sign of the expression, but not its magnitude, so it can be ignored in deciding whether $x_m\ne 0$.

Because $p,q$ are prime, $m\ge 6$. There are four cases to be considered: $\text{gcd}(m,n)=1;\ \text{gcd}(m,n)=p;\ \text{gcd}(m,n)=q;\ \text{gcd}(m,n)=pq=m$.

Case 1: Note that $\text{gcd}(m,n)=1 \Rightarrow \text{gcd}(p,n)=1;\ \text{gcd}(q,n)=1$, so all exponents in the expression become $1$. The sum simplifies to $a^m-a$ which for $a>1$ is not $0$.

Case 2: $\text{gcd}(m,n)=p$ makes two of the exponents $p$ and the other exponent $1$. The term with the exponent $1$ is cancelled by the term with no exponent, so what remains are two terms to power $p$. Now $(a^m-1)>(a-1) \Rightarrow (a^m-1)^p>(a-1)^p$, so once again $x_m\ne 0$

Case 3: The same argument can be made when $\text{gcd}(m,n)=q$

Case 4: The expression to be evaluated becomes $(a^m-1)^{pq}-(a-1)^p-(a-1)^q+(a-1)$ WLOG we can assume $p>q$, and examine the last three terms $(a-1)^p+(a-1)^q-(a-1)$ as their total will be subtracted.

$(a-1)^p>(a-1)^q>(a-1)^q-(a-1)$; therefore $2(a-1)^p>(a-1)^p+(a-1)^q-(a-1)$; hence $(a^m-1)^{pq}-(a-1)^p-(a-1)^q+(a-1)>(a^m-1)^{pq}-2(a-1)^p$ and $2(a-1)^p=(2^{\frac{1}{p}}(a-1))^p$

But taking $p^{th}$ roots, $(a^m-1)^q>(2^{\frac{1}{p}}(a-1))$ so the difference is $>0$, and also in this case $x_m\ne 0$