# A Problem on some Inequality of natural numbers

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I'm sorry butr I must to edit my question before. It is a Problem on the book of my supervisor on elementary number theory
Let $a,m,n\in\mathbb{N}$,$a>1$, $m=pq$, where $p,q$ are primes and define the number

$$x_{m}=(-1)^n[(a^\frac{m}{gcd(m,n)}-1)^{gcd(m,n)}-(a^\frac{q}{gcd(q,n)}-1)^{gcd(q,n)}-(a^\frac{p}{gcd(p,n)}-1)^{gcd(p,n)}+(a-1)]$$

I must to prove that $x_{m}\neq 0$

**My Aproach** Case 1: gcd(pq,n)=1. In this case

$$x_{m}=(-1)^{n}[a^{pq}-a^{p}-a^{q}+a]$$

Let suppose that $x_{m}=0$. Then

$$a^{pq}-a^{p}-a^{q}+a=0$$

$$\rightarrow a[a^{pq-1}-a^{p-1}-a^{q-1}+1]=0$$

$$\rightarrow [a^{pq-1}-a^{p-1}-a^{q-1}+1]=0$$

$$\rightarrow -a^{pq-1}+a^{p-1}+a^{q-1}=+1$$

$$\rightarrow a|1$$

which is imposible because $a>1$

Comment: So ... your question is what exactly.

Comment: No is Not the same question

Comment: What *is* your question?

Comment: I must to prove that $x_{m}\neq 0$ and in my previous version I did not write correctly

Comment: so edit it.... https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3349781/inequality-of-some-natural-numbers